# Book on stable homotopy theory?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, self-learning, stable-homotopy-theory

Currently I know nothing about stable homotopy theory other than that it originated from the Freudenthal suspension theorem. But I believe that the following are studied in this field: spectrum, generalized homology.

**Background**: I have been reading Tammo tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology* and have finished most of Chapters 1-6 and 8. These include: classical results on fundamental group(oid)s, covering spaces; suspension/loop space, Puppe sequences, fibrations/cofibrations; homotopy groups, exact sequences, higher connectivity, homotopy excision (Blackers–Massey), Freudenthal suspension theorem, Hopf–Brouwer degree theorem, Brouwer fixed point theorem; CW complexes, cellular approximation, CW approximation, Eilenberg–Mac Lane spaces.

**Questions**:

1. What are the prerequisites for stable homotopy theory?
2. Based on what I have learned, what text would you recommend for an introduction to stable homotopy theory?
3. Do I have to study homology theory before stable homotopy?

Comment: I was at this point a couple of months ago.  I found Akhil Mathew's notes to be an extremely good reference with my background almost exactly the same as yours (plus a bit more on spectral sequences/(co)homology) going into the topic: http://math.uchicago.edu/~amathew/256y.pdf.

Comment: @AlvinJin I've looked into the notes and it seems that they require a bit more than my background... Any recommendations for books that fill in the gap?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+Stable+Homotopy+Theory)'s what you're looking for, it also has the required background.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1128210)

Comment: My bad, next time i'll pay more attention